# Angular JS - How can i execute code only after completion of a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a function `AuthService.saveSession()` in `app.run`

and i am calling `AuthService.isLoggedIn()` in my `$stateChangeStart` function it say undefined because both functions are getting called at the same time.

How can i make my code to execute `$stateChangeStart` after `AuthService.saveSession()` is completed.

Hope i am explaining very clearly any queries please comment.

**Update**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, $http, $q, AuthService){

AuthService.saveSession();

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,fromParams){
alert(AuthService.isLoggedIn()); // It says undefined.

});
```

Comment: Can you post some of your actual code; it's impossible for anybody to help without it!

Comment: I don't want to guess buddy !!! Show some code!!!

Comment: If you have an async function, which you'll probably have, use callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $q and return a promise :

eg :

```
  function saveSession(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      //insert logic and async calls here
      //after everything is done, do this
      deferred.resolve(data); //where data is the data you want to get

      return deferred.promise;
  }
```

and call it that way :

```
  var promise = saveSession();
  promise.then(function(data){
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,fromParams){
        alert(AuthService.isLoggedIn());
      });
  });
```

Comment: can i write `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){}` after `then`?

Comment: from where `functionDelayed` is coming??

Comment: In fact, you can create an abonnement to an event into the "then", but I'm not sure you still need this abonnement here.

Comment: can u please simply explain the above function as i cant understand the `deffered logic`. I mean it will take only seconds for you to explain but will help me a lot

Comment: Thats pretty confusing and complicated so i asked you anyways it was a great help from you. May god bless you..:-) `alert('Thanks!');`

Comment: I understand, I often feel the same way as you. Although, in this case, I could not do better than the doc at explaining this

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach as you are using factory

```
 //factory for AuthService service , put $q in dependency in factory

 saveSession:function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //insert logic and async calls here
    //after everything is done, do this
    deferred.resolve(data); //where data is the data you want to get

    return deferred.promise;
}
   AuthService.saveSession().then(function(status){
     //do action here after getting promise
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState,fromParams){

  //do what ever you want
  });
  })
```

Comment: no i can't do it because it will connect to the server on every state change.